# I was supposed to count the unique digits in a number but getting this int object not iterable on 4th line and not sure how to fix it

Tags: python-3.x, list

```
x = int(input("Enter the number: "))
count = 0
for elements in range(0,10):
    for i in (x):
        if elements == i:
            count += 1
            break
print()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
x = input("Enter number: ")
count = 0
for elements in range(10):
    for t in x:
        if (int(t)==elements):
            count += 1
            break
print(count)
```

Comment: I believe this code worked my way out of the issue.

Answer (score 1):

That error raise because an integer is not an iterate object unlike strings, list, etc. So what you can do it's just work with a **string**, then use **set** (which get the unique values) and then **get the length** of it and you won't need to traverse with a for loop as below:

```
x = input("Enter the number: ")
unique_digits = set(x)
print(len(unique_digits))
```

Hope it will help you :)